# Show that $||x||_{\infty}\leq||x||_2$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Equivalent norms on $\Bbb R^d$:

Show that $||x||_{\infty}\leq||x||_2$. When is there equality?

My attempt:

Assume $x$ is the zero vector. Then $||x||_{\infty}=0=||x||_2$

Assume $x=\sum^d_{j=1}x_je_j$ where $e=(e_1,...,e_d)$ is the canonical basis for $\Bbb R^d$, and where $x_j=0$ for all $j$ except $1$. Then $||x||_{\infty}=1=||x||_2$

Now assume $x$ os none of the above. Then since $|y|=\sqrt{y^2}$ and for any $t\in \Bbb R$ $|y| < \sqrt{y^2+t^2}$. Hence $||x||_{\infty}<||x||_2$

Would this be correct?

Comment: Yes, but you went really quickly at the end. For any $x$, let $x_i$ be a coordinate such that $||x||_\infty=|x_i|$. Then $|x_i|<\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_d^2}=||x||_2$.

Comment: You haven't expressed yourself very clearly. You have to show that for any $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_d)\in\Bbb R^d$, $\max_i|x_i|\le\sqrt{\sum x_i^2}$. Where does $y$ fit into this?

Comment: @TonyK , I have showed that for one case. Would it be sufficient to just write it like Isaac Ren did, or do I have to prove it in some other way? The $y$ is just showing the basic example of what happens to the equality of the absolute value and square root when you add something to the square root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let 
$$
\mathbf{x} \colon= \left( x_1, \ldots, x_d \right)
$$
be any point in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then by definition
$$
\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_\infty \colon= \max_{ i \in \{1, \ldots, d \} } \left\lvert x_i \right\rvert.
$$
So we can conclude that
$$
\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_\infty = \left\lvert x_k \right\rvert
$$
for some $k \in \{ 1, \ldots, d \}$, and since 
$$
\left\lvert x_i \right\rvert \geq 0 
$$
for each $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, d \}$, therefore we obtain 
$$
\begin{align}
\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_\infty &= \left\lvert x_k \right\rvert \\
&= \sqrt{ \left( \left\lvert x_k \right\rvert \right)^2 } \\
&\leq \sqrt{ \sum_{i = 1}^d \left( \left\lvert x_i \right\rvert \right)^2 } \\
&= \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_2.
\end{align}
$$
And, 
$$
\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_\infty = \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_2
$$
if and only if
$$
\sqrt{ \sum_{i = 1}^d \left( \left\lvert x_i \right\rvert \right)^2 } = \left\lvert x_k \right\rvert 
$$
for some $k \in \{ 1, \ldots, d \}$, and the last equality holds if and only if
$$
 \sum_{i = 1}^d \left( \left\lvert x_i \right\rvert \right)^2 = \left( \left\lvert x_k \right\rvert \right)^2 ,
$$
which holds if and only if
$$
\left\lvert x_i \right\rvert = 0,
$$
and hence 
$$
x_i = 0
$$
for all $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, d \}$ except possibly for one value $k \in \{ 1, \ldots, d \}$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: for the equalities, would it be fine what I wrote above?

Comment: @ThePoorJew  I've just editted my answer to include the equality part of your question. Please have a look at my post once again and feel free to ask any questions that you may still have.

Comment: when you write "except for possibly one $k$", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @ThePoorJew this means that all the components of the vector $\mathbf{x}$ are zero, but ONE component can be non-zero.